# htaccess mod_rewrite to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file tree:

```
root
  -lib
  -config
  -public
      -img
      -css
      -js
      index.php
  .htaccess
```

.htaccess is in the root folder. Most requests should be rewritten to 
public/index.php?request=$1, but that is not the problem.

I want another rewriterule for images, css and javascript (or in general, every other file or directory in /public):

Instead of

`example.com/public/css/style.css`
I want the file to be available under
`example.com/css/style.css`

And Instead of

`example.com/public/newfolder/randomfile.txt`
I want the file to be available under
`example.com/newfolder/randomfile.txt`

So i have to keep this abstract.

I can't make it work properly, especially not the combination of both cases in one .htaccess  file.

This is the basic RewriteRule for files/folder that does not exist:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), if there is a real file corresponding to your request and then stop rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

# real files
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ public/$0 [L]

# everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Edit:

If a subfolder of root is used as project root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /subdir/

# real files
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/public/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ public/$0 [L]

# everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried that. The second rule is still applied, even if there is a real file existing.

Comment: @Daniel I had two errors in the rules. 1. rule: substitute the real file. 2. rule: don't rewrite real files.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I had to remove the leading slash in the first rule.